# Beat matching crossfade with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to implement a beat matching Crossfade feature using ExoPlayer. Basically I have a concept how it should work, but I find it hard to adapt it to ExoPlayer.

Let me please first write how I want to do this so you can understand the case.
As you probably know Beat Matching Crossfade let to seamlessly switch from one song to another. Additionally it adjusts second song tempo to the first song tempo during the crossfade.

So my plan is as follows:
1. Load song A and B so they both starts to buffer.
2. Decoded samples of song A and B are stored in buffers BF1 and BF2.
3. There would be a class called MUX which is a main buffer and contains both songs buffers, BF1 and BF2. MUX provides audio samples to the Player. Samples provided to the Player are BF1 samples or mixed samples from BF1 and BF2 if there is a crossfade.
4. When buffer reaches the crossfade point then samples are send to Analyser class so it can analyse samples from both buffers and modify them for crossfade. Analyser sends modified samples to MUX which updates it's main buffer.
When crossfade is finished then load a next song from playlist.

My main question is how to mix two songs so I can implement class like MUX.
What I know so far is that I can access decoded samples in MediaCodecRender.processOutputBuffer() method so from that point I could create my BF1 and BF2 buffers.

There was also an idea to create two instances of ExoPlayer and while first song is playing the second one is analysed and it's samples are modified for further crossfade, but I think it may be hard to synchronise two players so the beats would match.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Were you ever able to build the MUX class or make any progress on this?

Comment: @mmccabe  I couldn't make it that way. I did the gain crossfade instead. So basically you have two players with the current and next song loaded. Then when crossfade starts, you gradually decrease the first player volume and increase the second player volume. It was good enough for us. 
It was quite a long time ago though so maybe it's easier to implement beat matching crossfade now.

Comment: @MarcinAdamczewski how was your experience with 2 Exo players? Would you be so kind to share a solution  - the crossfade part only please.

Comment: @David I pasted the code in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Answering @David question about crossfade implementation it looks more or less like this. You have to listen for active player playback and call this method when you want to start crossfade. It's in RxJava but can be easily migrated to Couroutines Flow.

```
    fun crossfadeObservable(
        fadeOutPlayer: Player?,
        fadeInPlayer: Player,
        crossfadeDurationMs: Long,
        crossfadeScheduler: Scheduler,
        uiScheduler: Scheduler
): Observable<Unit> {
    val fadeInMaxGain = fadeInPlayer.audioTrack?.volume ?: 1f
    val fadeOutMaxGain = fadeOutPlayer?.audioTrack?.volume ?: 1f

    fadeOutPlayer?.enableAudioFocus(false)
    fadeInPlayer.enableAudioFocus(true)
    fadeInPlayer.playerVolume = 0f
    fadeInPlayer.play()
    fadeOutPlayer?.playerVolume = fadeOutMaxGain
    fadeOutPlayer?.play()

    val iterations: Float = crossfadeDurationMs / CROSSFADE_STEP_MS.toFloat()

    return Observable.interval(CROSSFADE_STEP_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, crossfadeScheduler)
            .take(iterations.toInt())
            .map { iteration -> (iteration + 1) / iterations }
            .filter { percentOfCrossfade -> percentOfCrossfade <= 1f }
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .map { percentOfCrossfade ->
                fadeInPlayer.playerVolume = percentOfCrossfade.coerceIn(0f, fadeInMaxGain)
                fadeOutPlayer?.playerVolume = (fadeOutMaxGain - percentOfCrossfade).coerceIn(0f, fadeOutMaxGain)
            }
            .last()
            .doOnTerminate { fadeOutPlayer?.pause() }
            .doOnUnsubscribe { fadeOutPlayer?.pause() }
}
```

const val CROSSFADE_STEP_MS = 100L

Comment: thank you very much - will study your approach (not familiar with Rx ...). And how is listener experience - is it smooth sound transition, any jumps? I have corssfade using MediaPlayer API and VolumeShaper which works fine - till it is not. :-)  Sometimes MediaPlayer not able to correctly report internal state and throws exception. Just FYI.

Comment: If you're not too familiar with RX then let me just write what it does. It iterates every 100 ms for duration of a crossfade. Every 100 ms the volume for fadeInPlayer is increased by a little and for the fadeOutPlayer decreased by a little. I guess it can be done using coroutines or even a Handler.
I used the ExoPlayer library instead of MediaPlayer. I didn't notice any jumps during the transition, seemed pretty smooth. It is subjective though :)